# Control Composability in HTML5?

Tags: html, controls

I am a fresh from XAML person. I am now building a HTML5 UI, where I need a dropdown box which will have items in a hierarchal view (need to have ul with li(s) inside dropdown). Each item also needs to have a check-box to its left. If this was XAML, I could've done it easily, because most elements are containers. But in HTML5, I've no idea what to do.

From my searching, what I've understood is that one way is to build a custom control using jQuery.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this in HTML5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is a jQuery (or any other JS UI Framework). You can also just use plain Javascript.

A combination of HTML and CSS is also possible. Just search "CSS Dropdown" and add some Checkboxes. I do not know a pure HTML5 solution.